# Detect the Pop of ChildViewController in the ParentViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Sorry if my question is not clear. But i want to detect that when my parent ViewConroller display than its came by calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` method in the ChildViewController or not.

I know the workarroud to pass the variable at the pop time to parentviewcontroller but if there is any default method to detect it than its better than workarround.

Comment: By parent view controller, do you mean rootViewController ?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer thanx for reply, No its an one of the VC in the Navigation stack.

Comment: Have a look at `isMovingFromParentViewController` and `isMovingToParentViewController`. The first is called when a view controller is pushed on the navigation stack of `UINavigationController`, while the second is called when the VC is being popped. Hence an `if ([self isMovingToParentViewController])` in a VC's `viewWillAppear` will tell you if the VC appears after being pushed or popped.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer i am checking that, Thanx

Comment: @n00bProgrammer one question this will detect pop in the childviewcontroller or the viewcontroller which has pushed it?

Comment: Both. in the childViewController, simply move the statement to `viewWillDisappear`. The condition here would be `isMovingFromParentViewController`. This will check if the VC is being removed from the navigation stack. If YES, it's a POP operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign parent vc as delegate of [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In

```
navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
```

You can check is self == viewController. If yes, this vc is shown after call one of pop methods in navigation controller.